# Can you geocode to a polygon?

Tags: geocoding

I have a postal code file, I want to geocode to that polygon (not point) so that I can perform some analysis on each of the polygons.  Sometimes more than one point will share the same polygon so it can't be a 1 to 1 join.

Comment: Which software do you want to use?

Comment: [ZIP codes aren't polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13114578/1048862)...

Comment: ESRI offers Zip Code Boundaries as polygons in a .lpk. http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest geocoding as normal, and then doing a "Spatial Join" or "Union" operation on the resultant points -> to the polygons of the postal codes. That might be more accurate and get the results you need.

Comment: Spatial join doesn't give me the unique ID I need, I will try union though.